# I need help creating a form with a Likert Scale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

hi I'm new in RoR and I need a bit of help I'm going to try to explain this in the best way I can (English is not my native language)

1: I have 3 types of users (inspirational, transformational, and relational) and each one of those should have a form with questions and responses Something like this (photo below) I have this model ([photo of the model](https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/secure.notion-static.com/1f37fb79-4c3d-499f-9726-ebef27c15a88/Screenshot_from_2022-06-01_11-40-25.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAT73L2G45EIPT3X45%2F20220606%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220606T200441Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Signature=62e12a309670400d1c457b7e109058cb65deb055a64d2dc4698eb61efaf8cc33&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=filename%20%3D%22Screenshot%2520from%25202022-06-01%252011-40-25.png%22&x-id=GetObject)) and this is my form ([photo of the form](https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/secure.notion-static.com/6940bdfc-f398-4f31-b009-8cf58264bad1/Screenshot_from_2022-06-01_11-42-34.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAT73L2G45EIPT3X45%2F20220606%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220606T200842Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Signature=705ba4eac30d565d6f314e2476f1c1087902b91cfbe116f517fcc183f94f9ae6&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=filename%20%3D%22Screenshot%2520from%25202022-06-01%252011-42-34.png%22&x-id=GetObject)) I know this is not going to work out because in the model I have the responses as boolean and in the form, I have declared as a string soo there is no way that a going to be able to save what the users send. and for now, a don't have associations.
[photo of the Likert scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRMME.png)

I don't know if this is the best approach to make that, what do you think? or I was thinking to make a model named question which has a question (string) and another model called responses with the possible responses as a boolean (maybe I don't even need the model question, IDK)

2: but then for each response, I have to give each user a response based in he's responses (for example if the user responds more than 50% "Siempre" I should return a text and another text if he responds "casi siempre" 60%....) I don't know how to make that. I need a suggestion, please

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up thinking of making the Likert scale as a range and passing the data as an array